# how to get value from ion-select and display in label

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am dynamically binding the drop-down and here I am unable to display the value which is selected by default label and also if I change the selection that value is also not displaying in the label.

Below is my code

```
 <p>{{locName}}</p>
    <ion-grid style="background:#fafafa">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-6 hidden>
          <!--<ion-label>Location</ion-label>-->
          <ion-select #sectionSelect [(ngModel)]="location" (ngModelChange)="optionsFn()"  hidden>
            <ion-option *ngFor="let opt of allowedData" [value]="opt.LocationId">{{opt.LocationName}}</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-col>

      </ion-row>

    </ion-grid>
```

in the **locName** I have to display the selected data

below is my typescript code

```
optionsFn(){
    this.dataone = location;
    this.locName = this.dataone.LocationName;
    console.log(this.locName);

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as follows,

```
optionsFn(){
    this.dataone = this.location;
    this.locName = this.dataone.LocationName;
    console.log(this.locName);
}
```

or pass the ngModel value to the function
in HTML

```
(ngModelChange)="optionsFn(location)"
```

and in TS

```
 optionsFn(value:any){
        this.dataone = value;
        this.locName = this.dataone.LocationName;
        console.log(this.locName);
    }
```

Comment: yeah if i follow the first way in the console displaying undefined

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-recjyy?file=pages/home/home.html check this sample

Comment: just now i got solution by using this way (ionChange)="onChange(sectionSelect.text)"   & in .ts file  onChange(CValue) {
    console.log(CValue);
    this.locName = CValue;
  }